# Как получить информацию о файле из подпапки с помощью BAT-команд?

Tags: windows, bat

Нужно получить время посл. изменения файла из заданной подпапки и сравнить его с временем одноимённого файла в текущей папке. Если файл в текущей папке новее, файл в подпапке заменяется им. Всё это делается в цикле `for`:

```
for %%x in (*.txt) do
```

С текущей папкой всё понятно: `%%~tx`. А вот как быть с вложенной папкой, я никак не пойму. Пытался зайти в указанную подпапку:

```
pushd %2
```

, но всё равно `%%~tx` выдаёт только время файла из текущей папки.

Upd: нагуглил про существование модификатора `%~$Path:I`, а также про отложенное раскрытие переменных с помощью `!var!`. Всё вроде бы хорошо, но сочетание `set time2 = %%~t$dir:x` (где `$dir` - путь к нужной папке) выдаёт мне дату вместе с путём к файлу. А попытка обрезать строку в виде `!time2:~0,16!` приводит к тому, что...

```
time2=~0,16
```

!

Что с этим делать?

Полный код:

```
rem @echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for %%x in (*.txt) do (
if not exist %2 md %2
set dir1=%cd%\%2
    if not %%x==%1 (
        if exist %2\%%x (
            set time1 = %%~tx
            set time2 = %%~t$dir1:x
            set time2 = %time2:~0,16%
            set time2
            if time1 GTR time2 copy %%x %2
        ) else copy %%x %2
    )
    rem pause
    if errorlevel 1 echo Ошибка копирования файла
)
```